# SSRS - how to avoid row breaking in print preview mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report. some times, In the print preview mode, a single row data is being split on to two pages. How can i avoid this? Is there any setting i am missing?

[image]

Comment: On the table in the Tablix Proprety in the General page check "Kep together on the one page if possiable". this have work for me on SSRS 2008r2.

Comment: @Hiten004, tried that, but dosent work for me! :(

Comment: Which version are you using and can you upload your desing layouy for this report?

Answer (score 1):

Set Keep Together option to true.

Comment: i did set that option, but no use. The problem still exists.